# Pointer to first element of C struct is the same as pointer to the struct. But not in C#: Interop problem

Tags: c#, c, interop

Sorry for title, I have an interop problem.
The C dll that I'm using request, in a function, a pointer to the first element of a struct, however this in C can be cast to a pointer to that struct, while this is not the same in C#. How can I "simulate" this behavior (I need to use that function in C#).

I'll post here a code snippet:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct lgLcdBitmapHeader
{
    public Formats Format;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
struct lgLcdBitmap
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    lgLcdBitmapHeader hdr;
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    lgLcdBitmap160x43x1 bmp_mono;
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    lgLcdBitmapQVGAx32 bmp_qvga32;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct lgLcdBitmap160x43x1 : IDisposable
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Format = LGLCD_BMP_FORMAT_160x43x1
    /// </summary>
    public lgLcdBitmapHeader hdr;
    /// <summary>
    /// byte array of size LGLCD_BMP_WIDTH * LGLCD_BMP_HEIGHT, use AllocHGlobal to make code safe
    /// </summary>
    public IntPtr pixels;

    public void SetPixels(byte[] value)
    {
        if (value.Length < (int)BitmapSizes.Size)
            throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format("Byte array must be at least of size {0}", (int)BitmapSizes.Size));

        if (pixels == IntPtr.Zero)
            pixels = Marshal.AllocHGlobal((int)BitmapSizes.Size);

        Marshal.Copy(value, 0, pixels, (int)BitmapSizes.Size);
    }

    public void GetPixels(byte[] arrayToBeFilled)
    {
        if (arrayToBeFilled.Length < (int)BitmapSizes.Size)
            throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format("Byte array must be at least of size {0}", (int)BitmapSizes.Size));

        Marshal.Copy(pixels, arrayToBeFilled, 0, (int)BitmapSizes.Size);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (pixels != IntPtr.Zero)
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pixels);
    }
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct lgLcdBitmapQVGAx32 : IDisposable
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Format = LGLCD_BMP_FORMAT_160x43x1
    /// </summary>
    public lgLcdBitmapHeader hdr;
    /// <summary>
    /// byte array of size LGLCD_QVGA_BMP_WIDTH * LGLCD_QVGA_BMP_HEIGHT * LGLCD_QVGA_BMP_BPP, use AllocHGlobal to make code safe
    /// </summary>
    public IntPtr pixels;


    public void SetPixels(byte[] value)
    {
        if (value.Length < (int)QVGABitmapSizes.Size)
            throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format("Byte array must be at least of size {0}", (int)QVGABitmapSizes.Size));

        if (pixels == IntPtr.Zero)
            pixels = Marshal.AllocHGlobal((int)QVGABitmapSizes.Size);

        Marshal.Copy(value, 0, pixels, (int)QVGABitmapSizes.Size);
    }

    public void GetPixels(byte[] arrayToBeFilled)
    {
        if (arrayToBeFilled.Length < (int)QVGABitmapSizes.Size)
            throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format("Byte array must be at least of size {0}", (int)QVGABitmapSizes.Size));

        Marshal.Copy(pixels, arrayToBeFilled, 0, (int)QVGABitmapSizes.Size);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (pixels != IntPtr.Zero)
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pixels);
    }
}
```

The problem is that the function ask for lgLcdBitmapHeader pointer

```
public extern static uint lgLcdUpdateBitmap([In] int device, [In] ref lgLcdBitmapHeader bitmap, [In] Priorities priority);
```

But this in C can be easily casted to *lgLcdBitmap160x43x1* or *lgLcdBitmapQVGAx32*, but not in C#
What should I do to effectively pass one of those 2 structs to the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should declare two overloads of your `extern` function that take two different `ref` struct parameters.

Comment: Mh, I'll try, I'm only afraid on how C will handle this. If it will not complain about this it's ok.

Comment: @Fire-Dragon-DoL: C isn't aware of struct pointer types.  .Net will generate calls to your C method with pointers to two different types of structs.  As long as the C code on the other end expects those pointers, it should work fine.

Comment: The problem is that C on the other end expects a pointer to lgLcdBitmapHeader and I can't edit it because I don't have sources of the lib.

Comment: @Fire: In C, a pointer to the struct is equal to a pointer to its first element.  Therefore, passing a pointer to the outer struct will work.